# OutputCache on server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, caching, outputcache

I define OutputCache attributes on top of my controller actions, so that the server can give the same response quickly to different users. Bu it caches the **whole** page. I mean the master page is also cached if I have cached an action that returns a `View()`. So the user account information on top of the master page gets shared by every user. I want to cache only the content page, not the master page, _Layout.cshtml. How can I exclude that?

Edit:
The part where I'm having trouble is this:

```
@if(Request.IsAuthenticated) {
    <text>Hello <strong>@User.Identity.Name</strong>!</text>
    @: | 
    @Html.ActionLink("Index", "Index", "Account")
    @: |
    @Html.ActionLink("Logout", "Logout", "Account")
}
else
{
    @:|
   @Html.ActionLink("Login", "Login", "Account")
}
```

When I cache a controller action, the returned view also carries this userlogin part from the cache, so it gives wrong salutes to almost every user. How can I dynamically generate this part even if the page is cached?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VaryByCustom is what you want.

Put this in your Global.asax:

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string custom)
{
    return "User".Equals(custom, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        ? User.Identity.Name
        : base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, custom);
}
```

...then use an `[OutputCache(VaryByCustom = "User")]` attribute.

This will still cause the whole page to be cached separately, but a separate cache will be created for each user.

If you are looking for other options, search for MVC donut caching or MVC donut hole caching.

**Reply to comment**

Sounds like you want donut hole caching. See if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685906/is-donut-caching-available-in-asp-net-mvc-3) helps you.

Comment: thanks, i need the login part to be generated dynamically, but the main content to be cached for any user.